# Weird Responsive image grid FireFox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design

I have a weird problem is firefox (not in google or safari) where you get 1px margin on the sides of the image when you move the window. I don't not if this a bug in firefox or I have just missed something, but it as been really annoying me.

**Update:** the first problem was fixed with a simple update to firefox, but the problem has came back after adding the transition to change the opacity.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
 html,
body,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: pink;
}
li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
li .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
li .text h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
li:hover img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
li:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>"Rubber Ducky"</h1>
      <small>001</small>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>"Rubber Ducky"</h1>
      <small>001</small>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>"Rubber Ducky"</h1>
      <small>001</small>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>"Rubber Ducky"</h1>
      <small>001</small>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can't reproduce FF 36.0 (on mac 10.9)

Comment: @Kaiido Yep It has a stupid mistake on my part.  I forgot to update firefox. I hang my head down in shame :(

Comment: @kaiido It has came back now afterI adding the transform ease-in-out